# Replace values in a list of lists

Tags: python, list, replace, text-mining

I have a list of lists and I need to replace some values. I need to replace smiles with their meaning, remove # (leaving just the word after) and remove links

```
 [['Dang', 'starting', 'next', 'week', 'I', 'work', ':('],
        ['oh', 'god', ',', 'babies', 'faces', ':(','https: //any/website'],
        ['make', 'smile', ':('],['Athabasca','glacier','#1948',':-(','#athabasca',
    '#glacier','#jasper','#jaspernationalpark','https: //any/website2'], ...]
```

I tried to do something like:

```
[[re.sub('#','',mylist) for word in sublist] for sublist in mylist]
```

or

```
[[re.sub('[:;=][\(]','sad',mylist) for word in sublist] for sublist in mylist]
```

but it doesn't work. I get an error saying "expected string or bytes-like object". 
Please help me!

Comment: You probably meant `re.sub('#','',word)`

Comment: That's right. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the following code as your syntax is incorrect.

```
[re.sub('#','',word) for mylist in sublist for word in mylist]
```